# Android notifyItemRemoved() Wrong Index notified

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, notify, notifydatasetchanged

Good day. I have a small chat app where i want to simply delete the chat item locally.

By debugging around i can reckon that there is something wrong with notifyItemRemoved() as follows :

• I have debugged the returned index from my List and the index was correct for list.

• I have debugged the returned Model Class from the ViewHolder and the returned model class was correct.

• I have debugged my custom `equals()` method inside my Model and it was comparing correctly returning correct item.

The main complain about my debugging is i dont know why,but the `equals()` method is being called 2 times...pretty weird though if you would have time please consider this case as well.

The main problem is the notifyItemRemoved() is always removing not the correct item,but always 1 item above the item which must be deleted (in means of deleted i mean deleted from the view as deleting from the list is happening correctly)

So i have no clue what is going on here.

Here is my custom `equals()` methods

```
  @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj instanceof ChatModel) {
        ChatModel chatModel = (ChatModel) obj;
        if (chatModel.getMessageId().equals(messageId)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return messageId.hashCode();
}
```

Here is how i insert items into adapter list.

For the list of models->

```
 public void insertChatModelWithItemNotify(List<ChatModel> chatModel, boolean firstPaging) {
    if (firstPaging) {
        this.chatModelList.addAll(chatModel);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        this.chatModelList.addAll(0, chatModel);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, chatModel.size());
    }
}
```

For a single model - >

```
    public void insertChatModel(ChatModel chatModel) {
    this.chatModelList.add(chatModel);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here is how i remove the item from the list

```
  public void removeItem(ChatModel chatModel) {
    int position = this.chatModelList.indexOf(chatModel);
    this.chatModelList.remove(chatModel);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `notifyItemRangeChanged` after `notifyItemRemoved`

Comment: By the way, are you adding some kind of header to the listview? Or doing some kind of logic that makes the object index in the list different from the view index in the recycler view?

Comment: Got damnnnn it............ aaaaa you are correct! i doing such thing......I have header and the returned size is different for adapter,but why that affect the actual list position? as the list is never being added any extra item only the message chat items are being added to list,but probably that is the case why the list is removed correctly and the view is not notified correctly,ok will try with +1 position,if worked,put that as an aswer

Comment: WOOHOOO worked!!!!!! perfect, Oh how that can be killing with forgetting some small thing....put this as an answer i will accept that

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: lol did it :D no worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably adding some kind of header to the RecyclerView which makes the object index in your object list different from the View index in the RecyclerView.